# How can I convert a NOT IN Clause into a left outer join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am trying to convert a query for better performance from a NOT IS clause to a left outer join.

the following is my query which works perfectly

```
SELECT a.company_code, account_name, legal_name FROM accounts a

WHERE account_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT  account_id FROM phone_calls WHERE status = 2 ) AND account_id >10000

ORDER BY legal_name, account_name, account_id
```

So I want to change it to a left join or some type of join that will do the same query.
I have tried this but it is not working for me

```
SELECT a.company_code, a.account_name, a.legal_name, p.phone_call_id
FROM accounts AS a
LEFT JOIN phone_calls AS p ON p.account_id = a.account_id

WHERE a.account_id >= 10000 AND p.status = 2 AND p.phone_call_id IS NULL

ORDER BY a.legal_name, a.account_name, a.account_id
```

my second query returns nothing always.

I have tried this query and this gives me more results that the first query so it is not the same

```
SELECT a.company_code, a.account_name, a.legal_name, p.phone_call_id
FROM accounts AS a
LEFT JOIN phone_calls AS p ON p.account_id = a.account_id AND p.status = 2 AND a.account_id >= 10000

WHERE p.account_id IS NULL

ORDER BY a.legal_name, a.account_name, a.account_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put the check for `p.status = 2` in the `join` clause, not in the `where` clause :

```
SELECT a.company_code, a.account_name, a.legal_name, p.phone_call_id
FROM accounts AS a
LEFT JOIN phone_calls AS p ON p.account_id = a.account_id AND p.status = 2
WHERE a.account_id >= 10000  
AND p.phone_call_id IS NULL

ORDER BY a.legal_name, a.account_name, a.account_id
```

If you put it in the where clause, phone_calls will be joined, and you will check after joining

- that p.status=2
- that p.phone_call_id IS NULL

these statements are probably in total conflict (all phone_calls with a status = 2 have an id).

And in general, you should not have a clause on a Left joined tabled in the WHERE clause (except `IS NULL` / `IS NOT NULL`)

Comment: this is correct, but I guess some pedagogy on the why and how would be welcome too

Comment: Okay this gave me results but it did not give me the same results. So it did not work.

Comment: @Mike, sure ? and phone_call_id is the pk (not nullable) on phone_calls table ?

Comment: Likely better to use `AND p.account_id IS NULL` to check for non-matches (in case phone_call_id is naturally null).

Comment: Yes I am sure. But when I remove the order by clause it works.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus  When I run the following query I get 63 records when I should be getting 52    SELECT a.company_code, a.account_name, a.legal_name, p.phone_call_id
FROM accounts AS a
LEFT JOIN phone_calls AS p ON p.account_id = a.account_id AND p.status = 2 AND a.account_id >= 10000  
WHERE p.phone_call_id IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, but try using a `NOT EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT company_code
     , account_name
     , legal_name 
FROM   accounts a
WHERE  account_id > 10000
   AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM phone_calls b
      WHERE b.status = 2 
        AND b.account_id = a.account_id
      )
ORDER BY legal_name, account_name, account_id
```

I think only an `EXPLAIN` will reveal which is the better technique.  Seems strange to ORDER the results by columns not selected, but that's a different question.

Comment: this query returns 52 records just like my very first query in my question. my third query in my question return 887 record but if i remove the order by I get 52.  so it is something with the order by

Comment: The third query in your question is different because you added the added `account_id >= 10000` to the `LEFT JOIN` condition.  That should be in your `WHERE` clause for the same effect.

Comment: I see that does make the results correct. but why when I use order by it pulls many records? what is the secret?

Comment: There must be something else different in your query; an `ORDER BY` clause by itself will not affect the result; it just **sorts** the result. The `ORDER BY` clause is the last processing step in a query.

Comment: I understand that but look at my query I execute it exactly how I have it posted. What else I can check for?